# hidden layer weights calculation

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, numpy

I've been working on neural network for a while and I built simple network from scratch with python but before using TensorFlow, I would like to have a complete understanding of it.

Here is my question :

Lets say you have 3 layers you have 3 weights to update :

1) --> the weight between the outputlayer and the hiddenLayer2

2) -->  the weight between the hiddenLayer2 and the hiddenLayer1

3) -->  the weight between the hiddenLayer1 and the inputLayer

For the 1) the calculation is quite simple we got :

```
weight_3 += LEARNING_RATE * ((2*(target - output)) * sigmoid'(output) * layer2)
```

For the 2) the calculation is more complicated  and we got :

```
weight_2 += LEARNING_RATE * ((2*(target - output)) * sigmoid'(output) * weight_3) * sigmoid'(hiddenLayer2)
```

I need help for the 3rd part, I tried to calculate and find on internet but not a lot of people uses 2 hidden layer when they work from scratch.

I also tried to resolve the **chain rule** but its too long and I can't resolve.

Does someone know the **formula** to get the weight between the **hiddenLayer1** and the **inputLayer** ?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/) is a good example of how to implement forward and backward propagation, in numpy, but there should be similar functions in tf.

Comment: I believe this is if in TF http://blog.aloni.org/posts/backprop-with-tensorflow/